# Make git use ssh key rather than username and password

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have a Jenkins pipeline script where I have this command:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

This in turn calls `git push` which works using this key for my Git repository:

```
ssh://git@my-repo.com/my-project.git
```

This is all good.

However, when i call git directly somewhere else in the script:

```
 git tag -l : xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

The key used is:

```
https://my-username:my-password@my-repo.com
```

And this doesn't work.

So how can I force git to use the SSH key?

Answer (score 1):

We do it like this with the [SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin):

```
sshagent([gitCredentials]) {
    sh "git commit -m 'update'"
    sh "git push -u -f origin release"
}
```

Comment: I've tried surrounding the code with this, where instead of `gitCredentials` I put my SSH key. However, nothing changed.

Comment: I don't know if that works, you should use the ID of the registered key. Have a look at the snippet generator.